# How can I save my carefully constructed printer presets before I have to re-install my printer?

Tags: macos, printing, system-settings, firmware

My Brother MFC-L5750DW is refusing to print documents (worked fine this morning), and after restarting, checking for latest software and drivers (currently updating) I suspect it's time to remove and re-add the printer via SysPrefs.

Over the last few months I have carefully saved up numerous printing presets which AFAIK will all be lost when I remove the printer.

I don't want that - what steps can I do to keep these presets - is there a .pref file somewhere?

Anything else I should do first?

OS 10.15.4
Mac Mini (Late 2012)
Printer Driver (and Firmware) updating as we speak (released yesterday)…

Thanks!

Comment: I recently migrated to Catalina and wanted to start clean so I had to find all my settings files manually - this was one of them.

Comment: Progress - lastest driver +Airprint - nothing. Latest version no Airprint, file printed. Now to re-import preferences…

Comment: Prefs all gone :(

Comment: :( Have to remake the prefs… even using Time Machine to bring them back didn't help

Comment: How so?  I copied my preferences from El Cap and they worked just fine.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Errrm… I copied the original prefs file to the desktop, deleted printer. Re-added it, dragged prefs back to user library, no dice. :(

Comment: Are the names exactly the same? Create a new setting so the file can get written.  Then you'll have the correct filename.  Then rename your original settings to that file.  Also, you'll have to view the file to make sure the name is consistent inside the file.

Comment: I‘m understood only some of that. I‘ll give it a go and get back to you, if i may

Comment: Also, restart your Mac.  When I did mine, I was installing and reconfiguring software so it got restarted at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Your custom presets are located in

```
${HOME}/Library/Preferences/com.apple.print.custompresets.plists
```

Now, it is possible that it may have the printer name "embedded" in the filename.  For instance I have an HP LaserJet that I name "HP Color LaserJet" so for me, my plist has the following name:

```
com.apple.print.custompresets.forprinter.HP_Color_LaserJet.plist
```

If you want to see what's in the settings file, just issue the command

```
defaults read com.apple.print.custompresets.forprinter.HP_Color_LaserJet.plist
```

Comment: Apparently, you renamed your "HP LaserJet" to "HP Color Las***d***erJet"... ;-)

Comment: @klanomath - [Such fail](https://media0.giphy.com/media/l0O9zrbtv8ALhvqi4/source.gif)!  Lasders are more cost effective though.